# how to insert textbox value with selected checkbox value

Tags: php

```
<form action="message1.php" method="post" >
<img height="150" width="200"src="<?php echo $images_dir."/tb_".$row[2]; ?>"/><input type='checkbox' name='chk1[]' value ='<?php echo basename($images_dir."/".$row[2]);?>'/><input type='text' name='textbox[]'id='textbox'/>     </br>


$checkbox1=$_POST['chk1'];
$txt =$_POST['textbox'];
if($_POST["submit"]=="submit") {
   for($i=0;$i<sizeof($checkbox1);$i  ) {
      if(!empty($txt)) {
```

$query="INSERT INTO message(item,quantity)VALUES('".$checkbox1[$i]."','".$txt."')";
            mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
          }
       }
     echo "message is send";

Comment: Can you make your question a little bit more clear? What do you want to accomplish? I guess you want to insert the textbox value into database based on which checkbox is checked?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post the multiple values from the same checkbox group then you have to take the checkbox field as in array like
type='checkbox' name='chk1[]' and when you are posting the value use the below code

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['chk1']);$i++) {
$checkval = $checkval.",".$_POST['chk1'][$i];
}

echo $checkval;
```

I hope I answered your question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$checkbox1=$_POST['chk1'];

if(!empty($_POST['chk1']))
{
    $txt = $checkbox1;
}
else
{
    $txt =$_POST['textbox'];
}

if($_POST["submit"]=="submit") {
   for($i=0;$i<sizeof($checkbox1);$i++) {
      if(!empty($txt)) {
        $query="INSERT INTO message(item,quantity) VALUES('".$checkbox1[$i]."','".$txt[$i]."')";
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
      }
   }
 echo "message is send";
}
```

Comment: <form action="message1.php" method="post" >
<li>
<img height="150" width="200"src="<?php echo $images_dir."/tb_".$row[2]; ?>"/>
<input type='checkbox' name='chk1[]' value ='<?php echo basename($images_dir."/".$row[2]);?>'/><input type='text' name='textbox[]'id='textbox'/></br>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['name1']))
    {
        $name1=implode(",",$_POST['name1']);
        if(!empty($_POST['name']))
        {
            $name=$_POST['name'];
            $name = $name .','. $name1;
        }
        else
        {
            $name=$name1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $name =$_POST['name'];
    }

    $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
    $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into t values('$name')");
    if($sql)
    {
        echo "Inserted!!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed to insert!!";
    }
}
?>
```